# tr bgcolor dependant on row value

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new to php and I have a table that displays cases from our support portal. Cases are set to a priority of "High, Medium, or Low" I want the bgcolor of each row to display a different color based on the priority of that case. For exacmple High = Red, Low = White, Medium = Yellow.

Below is the code I have. How would I go about implementing this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
<?php
              $priority = $val['priority'];
                  switch($priority)
                  {
                      case P3:
                       $prior_value = "Low";
                        break;
                      case P2:
                       $prior_value = "Medium";
                        break;
                      case P1:
                       $prior_value = "High";
                  }
?>

 <tr  height="30px">
    <Td class="gridcontentredmid" style="width:65px;"><a href="showcase.php?case_id=<?=$val['id']?>">
      <?=$val['case_number']?>
      </a></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:270px; text-align:left;">&nbsp;
      <?=$val['name']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:85px;" ><?=$val['status']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid"><?=$name?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:65px;"><?=$prior_value?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmidd" style="border-right:#000 1px solid"><?=$date_create?></Td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I assume P3 is a string not a Constant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `$color`-variable to your `switch`, which then can be inserted in the `TR`s `class` or `style` attribute.

```
switch($priority)
{
    case P3:
        $prior_value = "Low";
        $bgColor = '#fff';
        break;
    case P2:
        $prior_value = "Medium";
        $bgColor = '#ff0';
        break;
    case P1:
        $prior_value = "High";
        $bgColor = '#f00';
}
```

…

```
<tr style="background-color: <?php echo $bgColor; ?>;">
```

Comment: Thank you feeela.. worked like a champ. I tried that before but I couldn't figure the <?php echo $bgColor; ?> thing out.

Comment: @ipengineer: As @minitech stated, you better should use CSS-classes instead of inline-CSS (see his/her answer).

Comment: Done. Switched it over to CSS. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick way:

```
              $priority = $val['priority'];
                  switch($priority)
                  {
                      case P3:
                       $prior_value = "Low";
                        break;
                      case P2:
                       $prior_value = "Medium";
                        break;
                      case P1:
                       $prior_value = "High";
                  }
                  $colors = array("High" => "red", "Medium" => "yellow", "Low" => "white");
                  $color = $colors[$prior_value];


 <tr style="background-color: <?php echo $color; ?>" height="30px">
    <Td class="gridcontentredmid" style="width:65px;"><a href="showcase.php?case_id=<?=$val['id']?>">
      <?=$val['case_number']?>
      </a></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:270px; text-align:left;">&nbsp;
      <?=$val['name']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:85px;" ><?=$val['status']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid"><?=$name?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:65px;"><?=$prior_value?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmidd" style="border-right:#000 1px solid"><?=$date_create?></Td>
  </tr>
```

But a much better way would be to use CSS:

```
.priorityHigh {
    background-color: red;
}

.priorityMedium {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.priorityLow {
    background-color: white;
}
```

and

```
              $priority = $val['priority'];
                  switch($priority)
                  {
                      case P3:
                       $prior_value = "Low";
                        break;
                      case P2:
                       $prior_value = "Medium";
                        break;
                      case P1:
                       $prior_value = "High";
                  }


 <tr class="priority<?php echo $prior_value; ?>" height="30px">
    <Td class="gridcontentredmid" style="width:65px;"><a href="showcase.php?case_id=<?=$val['id']?>">
      <?=$val['case_number']?>
      </a></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:270px; text-align:left;">&nbsp;
      <?=$val['name']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:85px;" ><?=$val['status']?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid"><?=$name?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmid" style="width:65px;"><?=$prior_value?></Td>
    <Td class="gridcontentmidd" style="border-right:#000 1px solid"><?=$date_create?></Td>
  </tr>
```